# How to execute a .bat to run multiple files in a timed sequence?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I am wanting to write a simple batch file. It will pick up a file from a directory, let's say **D:\scripts\script1.conf**, and let's it run. I then want there to be a 60 second delay, and have the same batch file pick up **D:\scripts\script2.conf**, and so on.

How would it be possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start "" "D:\scripts\script1.conf"
timeout /t 60 /nobreak > NUL
start "" "D:\scripts\script2.conf"
timeout /t 60 /nobreak > NUL
```

So this will run one file, wait for 60 seconds, and run the second.
`start` will open the file by its type-linked-program.
The first parameter "" specify the window title it started -- If the program can be titled.

You can incorporate these with `for` and `goto` to loop through some files or other conditions.

Comment: If you are not sure what the OP meant, flag the post as unclear, or too broad.

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm not using colloquial lingo. "Pickup" means "to run the .conf file."

Answer (score 0):

I expect you need a solution for Windows.

You could use this to have a delay of 60 seconds in your batch:

```
@ping -n 60 localhost> nul
```

If you already use Windows Vista or higher, you also could use this:

```
@timeout /T 60
```

or this to prevent the user could break the delay by pressing a key:

```
@timeout /T 60 /nobreak
```

Comment: I don't think that the OP wanted to learn how to `timeout`!